# Use "Binding" class to listen property path changes for code-behind operations

Tags: c#, xaml

Binding class provides listening for property paths

Example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding A.B.C.D.E}" />
```

Reflects any change in the property chain

I want to utilize this mechanism in code behind.

What I want to do:

```
var binding = new Binding{
    Source = ViewModel,
    Path = new PropertyPath("A.B.C.D.E")
};
// not available
binding.ResultChanged += OnBindingResultChanged;
```

But "Binding" doesn't provide any events

Comment: A binding requires a dependency property as the target. The binding by itself doesn't do anything. It is a descriptor, which the binding engine uses when you _set_ it using the `SetBinding()` method, to know what properties and events to monitor to update the value. If you want to leverage that, you need to create a `DependencyObject` with a `DependencyProperty` which you use as the target of the binding.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use the Onpropertychanged Event.
You implement it like this

```
public class YourClass : window, INotifyPropertyChanged

    public string A.B.C.D.E {Get ; set ;}

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

after this in your XAML you can raise an event when the property is changed.

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding A.B.C.D.E}" textchanged="YOURMETHODENAME"/>
```

When this methode is called you can change the value of the property in the code behind.

```
public void YOURMETHODENAME (sender e, routeeventargs)
{
    //dostuff with your property
    OnPropertyChanged ("A.B.C.D.E)
}
```

this way you can change the value from the property in the code behind and from user input.

Comment: A.B.C.D.E is a chained expression
like CurrentUser.Address.City